# Anymation changes color to black when it should keep the gradient

Tags: css, css-animations

As a case study I was trying to replicate what hyperplexed brings up at the end of the video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owpaafxvkjU&ab_channel=Hyperplexed

i tried to apply the gradient to the words, however, by doing so the color of the word changes to back (even though the word split effect still happens)

I have tried to do it on hover, tried to change the colors, but still happens.

```js
const enhance = (id) => {
  const element      = document.getElementById('split');
  const text         = element.innerText.split('');
  element.innerText  = '';

  text.forEach((letter) => {
    const span      = document.createElement('span');
    span.className  = 'letter';
    span.innerText  = letter;
    element.appendChild(span);
  });
};

const enhance1 = (id) => {
  const element      = document.getElementById('split1');
  const text         = element.innerText.split('');
  element.innerText  = '';

  text.forEach((letter) => {
    const span      = document.createElement('span');
    span.className  = 'letter';
    span.innerText  = letter;
    element.appendChild(span);
  });
};

const enhance2 = (id) => {
  const element      = document.getElementById('split2');
  const text         = element.innerText.split('');
  element.innerText  = '';

  text.forEach((letter) => {
    const span      = document.createElement('span');
    span.className  = 'letter';
    span.innerText  = letter;
    element.appendChild(span);
  });
};

const enhance3 = (id) => {
  const element      = document.getElementById('split3');
  const text         = element.innerText.split('');
  element.innerText  = '';

  text.forEach((letter) => {
    const span      = document.createElement('span');
    span.className  = 'letter';
    span.innerText  = letter;
    element.appendChild(span);
  });
};

enhance('split');
enhance('split1');
enhance2('split2');
enhance3('split3');
```

```css
body {
  background-color : #000;
  margin           : 0;
  display          : flex;
  flex-direction   : column;
  align-items      : center;
  justify-content  : center;
  height           : 100vh;
  }
.line {
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
  }
p,
a {
  color           : #fff;
  font-size       : 5vw;
  font-family     : 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  margin          : 0rem;
  text-transform  : uppercase;
  }
a {
  text-decoration : none;
  }
#text:has(.fancy:hover) .word:not(.fancy:hover) {
  opacity         : 0.4;
  }
.fancy > .letter {
  display         : inline-block;
  transition      : transform 350ms ease;
  }
.fancy:hover > .letter {
  transition-duration: 800ms;
  }
.fancy:hover > .letter:nth-child(1) { transform : translate(-80%, 60%) rotate( 8deg); }
.fancy:hover > .letter:nth-child(2) { transform : translate(0%, 8%)    rotate(-6deg); }
.fancy:hover > .letter:nth-child(3) { transform : translate(-10%, 60%) rotate(-6deg); }
.fancy:hover > .letter:nth-child(4) { transform : translate(0%, 8%)    rotate(-8deg); }
.fancy:hover > .letter:nth-child(5) { transform : translate(0%, 60%)   rotate(-3deg); }
.fancy:hover > .letter:nth-child(6) { transform : translate(0%, 20%)   rotate(-3deg); }
.fancy:hover > .letter:nth-child(7) { transform : translate(0%, 80%)   rotate(-5deg); }

@keyframes background-pan
  {
  from { background-position:    0% center; }
  to   { background-position: -200% center; }
  }

p,
a,
.letter > .magic {
  animation               : background-pan 15s linear infinite;
  background              : linear-gradient(to right,#ecf2ff,#e3dffd,#e5d1fa,#fff4d2,#ecf2ff);
  -webkit-background-clip : text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color : transparent;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="text">
  <div class="line magic">
    <a href="#" class="word fancy" id="split">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="line magic">
    <a href="#" class="word fancy" id="split1">About</a>
  </div>
  <div class="line magic">
    <a href="#" class="word fancy" id="split2">Shop</a>
  </div>
  <div class="line magic">
    <a href="#" class="word fancy" id="split3">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone knows what it's causing the color to change to black please let me know, or point me towards some documentation so I can have a read through.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I should be calling the gradient inside the .fancy>letter instead of getting the p,a and letter.

it now works as intended